# How do I Insert Google Calendar Event using Google Api 3 for any user in the domain?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Api v3 (PHP Libraries) and wish to add an event to a user's calendar in our Google Apps domain.  I have created a client ID in the Google Developer console and have granted access to it under Security in our Google Apps Admin Console.  However, the event will only insert into a user's calendar if the User has previously granted access to the developer account.  I do not wish every user in our domain to have to grant the developer account access to their calendar.

Is it possible under API v3 to be able to seamlessly add an event to a user's calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Granting domain-wide delegation to your service account in the Google Apps Admin Console doesn't give it access to everyone's calendar. Instead it allows the service account to impersonate any given user within your domain, and then make requests as that user.

In the PHP client library you can impersonate a user by setting the `sub` field on the `Google_AssertionCredentials` object you created.

```
$auth->sub = $userEmail;
```

We don't have a complete sample showing this for the Calendar API, but the Drive API documentation includes [a sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object), and the process is identical.

Comment: Eric, Do you have any complete sample showing this for the Calendar API

Comment: No, but as mentioned the Drive API sample is almost identical.

Comment: thanks Eric.I tried like that. But not working in different domain user email id

Comment: Eric, My API CONSOLE in DOMAIN1.COM, nd end user is in DOMAIN2.COM. using test@domain1.com working fine, but using test2@domain2.com not working getting error. Plz help me how to solve this

Comment: You need to grant delegated authorization in each domain you want to use the service account.

Comment: @EricKoleda Sorry this is an old question. But you said "
1
down vote
Granting domain-wide delegation to your service account in the Google Apps Admin Console doesn't give it access to everyone's calendar." But how can I insert and edit events from my web app/server without them actually being present? For example, two-way sync...